# Eclipse: how to switch between console window and editor?

Tags: eclipse, tabs, switch-statement, hotkeys

I'm using Eclipse for Python and R development. How can I jump between editor tab and console window using a keyboard shortcut / hotkey?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go view Console: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

You can switch to Editor using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> displays all the shortcuts in Eclipse.

Comment: How do you perform `Shift + Alt + Q + C` ?

Comment: @agoldev Press `Shift` + `Alt` + `Q` and the same time, then you can release them and then press `C`. Eclipse will list you all possible shortcuts on the bottom right after you‘ve pressed `Shift` + `Alt` + `Q` that are possible with this combination (normally to open/focus a view).

Answer (score 7):

**I've found the following works:**

Toggle between views: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Switch Editor: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

Go to R Console (In StatET perspective): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

However, the first two are not a direct route back to the editor and require use of the arrow keys and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> does not work for me. Any other ways to go *directly* back to the last editor used?

Answer (score 0):

For RStudio:

- `Ctrl+1` : focus to source
- `Ctrl+2` : focus to console

More shortcuts are mentioned under the 'View' menu.